# cloudformation templates for alaram dashboard

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created CloudFormation templates for CloudWatch dashboard and I am trying to use the `AlarmName` parameter but Ref value not passing as well as getting error in AWS CloudFormation below.

```
The field DashboardBody must be a valid JSON object (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterInput;
Request ID: e88b103e-8fba-42bc-b825-ed0e4bd6749a; Proxy: null)
```

Template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template for Cloudwatch alert and Dashboard configuration."
Parameters: 
    AlarmNameForCPU: 
    Default: Service_CpuUtilization
    Description: AlarmName
    MaxLength: "99"
    MinLength: "1"
    Type: String
    AlarmNameForMemory: 
    Default: Service_MemoryUtilization
    Description: AlarmName
    MaxLength: "99"
    MinLength: "1"
    Type: String
    DashboardName: 
    Default: ServiceDashboard
    Description: Dashboard
    MaxLength: "99"
    MinLength: "1"
    Type: String
    DashboardTitleCPU: 
    Default: CpuUtilization
    Description: DashboardTitle
    MaxLength: "99"
    MinLength: "1"
    Type: String
    DashboardTitleMemory: 
    Default: MemoryUtilization
    Description: DashboardTitle
    MaxLength: "99"
    MinLength: "1"
    Type: String
Resources:
    Dashboard:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard"
    Properties:
        DashboardName: !Ref DashboardName
        DashboardBody: '{
    "widgets":[
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 9,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "title": "{"Ref DashboardTitleCPU"}",
                "annotations": {
                    "alarms": [
                        "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:468491150671:alarm: {"Ref" : "AlarmNameForCPU"}"
                    ]
                },
                "view": "singleValue"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 9,
            "y": 0,
            "x": 9,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "title": "{"Ref DashboardTitleMemory"}",
                "annotations": {
                    "alarms": [
                        "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:468491150671:alarm: {"Ref AlarmNameForMemory"}"
                    ]
                },
                "view": "singleValue"
            }
        }
    ]
}}}}]}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [Sub function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) for that.

```
Resources:
  Dashboard:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard"
    Properties:
      DashboardName: !Ref DashboardName
      DashboardBody: !Sub |
'{
        "widgets":[
            {
                "height": 3,
                "width": 9,
                "y": 0,
                "x": 0,
                "type": "metric",
                "properties": {
                    "title": "${DashboardTitleCPU}",
                    "annotations": {
                        "alarms": [
                            "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:468491150671:alarm:${AlarmNameForCPU}"
                        ]
                    },
                    "view": "singleValue"
                }
            },
            {
                "height": 3,
                "width": 9,
                "y": 0,
                "x": 9,
                "type": "metric",
                "properties": {
                    "title": "${DashboardTitleMemory}",
                    "annotations": {
                        "alarms": [
                            "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:468491150671:alarm:${AlarmNameForMemory}"
                        ]
                    },
                    "view": "singleValue"
                }
            }
        ]
    }'
```

Comment: I have used Sub function, but getting the same error.

The field DashboardBody must be a valid JSON object (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterInput;

Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DashboardBody} does not match type {String}]